# Write into a json data file without rewriting the whole thing?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm using a json file as a data source in a small app written in C#. I spent last evening looking after the best ways to do CRUD actions with a json data source and the one thing bugging me is that it doesn't seem possible to add/modify data without serializing the whole file to my class, adding an item to the list/updating an item then rewrite the whole thing to the file.

Something like that, which I'd like to avoid if possible :

```
 var allUsers = jData.ToObject<List<JsonEntry>>();
            allUsers.Add(newEntry);
            var convertedItems = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allUsers, Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText("UsersConfiguration.json", convertedItems);
```

Any idea on how to handle writing/updating in a better way ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What data structure are you trying to implement? Is this just a single collection of items? Multiple collections? Do they have relationships?

Comment: How do you expect to manipulate the text in the file without re-writing it? AFAIK, that can't be done in plain c#.

Comment: If you don't want to serialize to a class then you can follow one of the mentioned approach 1) Use `JsonTextReader` and `JsonTextWriter` of `NewtonSoft` 2) Serialzie to `JObject` and update the value and `deserialize` back to Json string to write to file.

Comment: @bommelding I couldn't agree more but there are options if the OP's data structure is really simple

Comment: @DanielleSummers simple or not, JSON is a **hierarchical** data structure persisted as **text**.  Both of these conditions make it highly improbable that one can perform partial serialisation

Comment: @user1672994 the issue is not that I don't want to serialize to a class is that I don't know how not to grab the whole file and rewrite it as a whole just to update or add an entry.

Comment: @bommelding I know that it's just that I know in advance that I won't get a lot of data and also that it will never happen that 1000 users will read/write on my data so instead of going the DB way I figured using a flat file for storage would be easier.

Comment: Let's suppose you have a facility to insert arbitrary text in another text file. How would you know where to insert?

Answer (score 2):

You could engineer something involving json chunks, but it would be hacky. The safest way is to carry on as you are, or maybe consider a NoSQL database since you're up against the "if only this file wasn't really a file" problem :P

Comment: The thing is, I'm using json flat file because I know I won't have a lot of data and it will never happen that 1000 users are going to read/write/update on it at the same time. From what I see on the Net and the answers here I'm doomed to carry on like this.

Comment: Haha, doomed is a good word for when a better solution isn't worth the effort. Beware thinking it's only small and not many people use it, I currently maintain a 20year old system used by about 30 people, and if they hire 2 more staff, this thing will race condition and file-lock itself into oblivion :P